# Are there any guidelines / best practices / patterns on how to manage application and view state in Win 10 – UWP?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I am looking after guidelines / best practices / patterns on how to manage application and view state in Win 10 – UWP. I am looking specifically how to address the following scenarios:

- How to save and restore page state on navigating forward and then back.
- How to handle the scenario when the application is suspended, terminated and then restored.
- A combination of the two where the user navigates forward to pages, then the application is suspended, terminated and then restored and then the user navigates back.

I remember that in Windows Phone 7.5 there were some very clear rules on how to deal with these scenarios. Since Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 I felt that things became a little bit murkier. I am transitioning to Win 10 UWP and I would like to get onto a more rigorous footing regarding how to address these scenarios.

For some reasons this subject is not well covered. Even for Win 8.1, resources that cover app and page life cycle only scratch the surface when it comes to state management. The fact that pages have since Win 8 / Win Phone 8.1 the NavigationCacheMode attribute offers more flexibility but probably complicates the matter of defining clear and simple patterns in this area. VS 2013 does generate a SuspensionManager class in some of the project templates but I heard people considering that deficient and writing their own. If anyone has experience with that I would be interested into hearing details about what aspects of the auto-generated SuspensionManager are not satisfactory and how a good one would look like. For Win 10 / UWP resources on the subject are even harder to find.

Any links, articles, books or any other resources on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: @EliasNicolas UWP is relatively new. Even when it comes to Win 8.1 there are no complete answers. Links that explain the app or page lifecycle just scratch the surface re state management. Microsoft in their efforts to unify the programming model across devices got into a situation where the app and view state management is a little bit confusing. This area may suffer a little bit from an identity crisis because they are striving to be universal across all devices. I hope that there may be some answers in blogs, video presentations or books that simply don’t surface high in google results.

Comment: I just asked a relevant question, since you didn't provide details of your research or what you did. You just demanded answers.

Comment: Related: [UWP/WinRT: How to save and then restore a simple TextBox for resume from termination?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977234/uwp-winrt-how-to-save-and-then-restore-a-simple-textbox-for-resume-from-termina) Recommendations for links/ libraries are off topic on Stack Overflow as they tend to attract spam answers. You may want to remove those from your question.

Comment: Go through the Developer's Guide to Windows 10 training course from MVA here: https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developer-s-guide-to-windows-10-12618.  Will cover all of these questions, particularly session 6 on application lifecycle.

Comment: Also take a look at Template10, a base template for UWP apps written by Jerry Nixon @ Microsoft https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10, to see how he handles things like lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that by reusing the SuspensionManager class from the Windows 8.1 templates that it supports everything I need for managing state.

I wrote about it here: http://blog.falafel.com/windows-10-development-maintaining-application-state/

as part of an ongoing series on windows 10 development. if you're looking for a quick and simple solution for state management this might just do the trick (tho I definitely recommend you check out [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) as well)

I hope this is helfpul!